# C# Bitmap: System.ArgumentException "Invalid parameter."

Tags: c#, bitmap

Faced such a problem "System.ArgumentException", while writing an envelope from an image (.jpg) in a text file with a picture (ASCII). Did according to the instructions (https://www.bilibili.com/video/av5862027/)

For the second or third day I try to solve this problem.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ayy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"meme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            for (int imageNumber = 0; imageNumber <= 7600; imageNumber++)
            {
                string url = @"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\badapple\ayy\ba\ba";
                if (imageNumber < 10)
                {
                    url += "00000";
                }
                else if (imageNumber < 100)
                {
                    url += "0000";
                }
                else if (imageNumber < 1000)
                {
                    url += "000";
                }
                else
                {
                    url += "00";
                }
                url += imageNumber.ToString() + ".jpg";
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(url, true);

                for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
                {
                    string str = "";
                    for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                    {
                        Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                        if (pixel.R > 200)
                        {
                            str += "#";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str += " ";
                        }
                        writer.WriteLine(str);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(url);
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The *exact location* and *message* of the exception (ie. the full exception trace) should make the problem (or at least where it occurs) 'relatively obvious'; this question contains neither.

Comment: Also, calling   `Bitmap image = new Bitmap(url, true);` with disposing or using the `using` statement is a one way street to an `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do

Comment: Make ascii image

Comment: Have you tried putting the Boolean parameter as false. I have done a little research and it suggests it does some processing on the file. It is possibly not required.

Comment: Most likely: __The old file doesn't exist.__ - -  Other than that we need the exact line number and message of the error. - And: You are leaking resource all over the code. See the general's answer!! - Also: Shouldn't you write your ascii line after each row, not each pixel?

Answer (score 1):

`using`, `using`, `using`

- Every time you go to play with something (or create an object) check if you can use a `using` statement
- If you expect a file to be there, do some due diligence and check if it exists
- If you want to join paths and file names, use `Path.Combine()`
- `GetPixel` is extremely slow, so probably better to use `LockBits`
- Why use lots of `if`s to add `0`'s when you can use a format specifier  `$"{imageNumber:D5}.jpg"`

Truthfully, i am not sure if this will fix your problem, but you are much better place regardless

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"meme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
   {
      for (var imageNumber = 0; imageNumber <= 7600; imageNumber++)
      {
         var dir = @"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\badapple\ayy\ba\ba";

         var fileName = Path.Combine(dir, $"{imageNumber:D5}.jpg");

         if (File.Exists(fileName))
         {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"Woah, what now : {fileName}");
         }

         using (var image = new Bitmap(fileName, true))
         {
            for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
               for (var x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
               {
                  var pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                  writer.Write(pixel.R > 200 ? "#" : " ");
               }

               writer.WriteLine();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you are still having problems, work out what file is causing the problem, check to see if it is actually an image and loads. My spidey senses tells me its not

Comment: This error still comes out, but thanks for the help, I will try to solve the problem

Comment: Is the file you loading actually an image?

Comment: I am trying to convert several images into one text file in order to create an animation in the console in another project

Comment: @H0d3ine that didnt answer the question, when it fails, it it trying to load a real image? have you double checked this

Comment: it does not load anything

Comment: Wild guess: __The images do not exist.__